# SDL_gfx 2.0.24 DLL is not build, using MinGW

Tags: dll, windows-7, 64-bit, mingw, sdl

I am setting up the Simple Direct Media Layer Library for my 64 bit Windows 7 system. The basic library works fine with both MinGW and Free Pascal, but currently I want to include the SDL_gfx library. The online tutorial I found, says, that I have to build my own DLL for the Windows system. [Link to the Tutorial. Chapter 4a is about GFX](http://www.freepascal-meets-sdl.net/)

I followed the steps and changed the makefile accordingly. But when I run "mingw32-make" in the gfx folder, it aborts with the error message "undefined reference to 'GFX_ALPHA_ADJUST_ARRAY'". Afterwards this message is repeated again, but points to a different part of the source code. Then "ld.exe" aborts with the message "bad reloc address 0x0 in section '.data'". "collect2.exe" fails, too, because "ld" returned 1 as end status. Then the makefile complains, that the "recipe for target 'SDL_gfx.dll' failed".

I own a Linux laptop, so I thought it might help to try and compile everything there, but I do not know how complicated that might be. So basically I ask for advice what to do. In terms of debugging, I reinstalled the whole SDL library several times and tested, if it works correctly. The other DLL, I installed (SDL_image.dll), works fine as well.

I already looked on the internet for precompiled DLLs, but they are either outdated or for 32 bit systems. But if nothing else works, this might be a solution as well. I will post the makefile and the parts of the source code, where the variable is missing as well.

**Makefile**

```
    CC = gcc
    AR=ar rc
    RANLIB=ranlib

    prefix=C:/
    bin_dir=$(prefix)/bin
    include_dir=$(prefix)/include
    lib_dir=$(prefix)/lib

    CFLAGS = -O3 -march=athlon-xp -mmmx -msse -m3dnow -DBUILD_DLL -IC:/MinGW/include/SDL
    LIBS = -LC:/MinGW/lib -lSDL

    OBJS = SDL_framerate.o SDL_gfxPrimitives.o SDL_imageFilter.o SDL_rotozoom.o

    STATIC_LIB=libSDL_gfx.a
    IMPORT_LIB=libSDL_gfx.dll.a
    SHARED_LIB=SDL_gfx.dll

    all: $(STATIC_LIB) $(SHARED_LIB)

    $(STATIC_LIB): $(OBJS)
    $(AR) $@ $^
    $(RANLIB) $@

    $(SHARED_LIB): $(OBJS)
gcc -s -shared -o $@ $^ -Wl,--enable-auto-import,--export-all -Wl,--out-implib=$(IMPORT_LIB) $(LIBS)

    test: $(SHARED_LIB) $(STATIC_LIB) Test/TestFramerate.exe Test/TestFonts.exe
    Test/TestGfxPrimitives.exe Test/TestImageFilter.exe Test/TestRotozoom.exe

    Test/TestFramerate.exe: Test/TestFramerate.c
gcc -c $^ -o Test/TestFramerate.o -O3 -march=athlon-xp -mmmx -msse -m3dnow -DWIN32 -Ic:/dev/local/include/SDL
gcc -o $@ Test/TestFramerate.o $(CFLAGS) -L../ -Lc:/dev/local/lib -lmingw32 -lSDLmain $(SHARED_LIB) -lSDL

    Test/TestFonts.exe: Test/TestFonts.c
gcc -c $^ -o Test/TestFonts.o -O3 -march=athlon-xp -mmmx -msse -m3dnow -DWIN32 -Ic:/dev/local/include/SDL
gcc -o $@ Test/TestFonts.o $(CFLAGS) -L../ -Lc:/dev/local/lib -lmingw32 -lSDLmain $(SHARED_LIB) -lSDL

    Test/TestGfxPrimitives.exe: Test/TestGfxPrimitives.c
gcc -c $^ -o Test/TestGfxPrimitives.o -O3 -march=athlon-xp -mmmx -msse -m3dnow -DWIN32 -Ic:/dev/local/include/SDL
gcc -o $@ Test/TestGfxPrimitives.o $(CFLAGS) -L../ -Lc:/dev/local/lib -lmingw32 -lSDLmain $(SHARED_LIB) -lSDL

    Test/TestImageFilter.exe: Test/TestImageFilter.c
gcc -c $^ -o Test/TestImageFilter.o -O3 -march=athlon-xp -mmmx -msse -m3dnow -DWIN32 -Ic:/dev/local/include/SDL
gcc -o $@ Test/TestImageFilter.o $(CFLAGS) -L../ -Lc:/dev/local/lib -lmingw32 -lSDLmain $(SHARED_LIB) -lSDL

    Test/TestRotozoom.exe: Test/TestRotozoom.c
gcc -c $^ -o Test/TestRotozoom.o -O3 -march=athlon-xp -mmmx -msse -m3dnow -DWIN32 -Ic:/dev/local/include/SDL
gcc -o $@ Test/TestRotozoom.o $(CFLAGS) -L../ -Lc:/dev/local/lib -lmingw32 -lSDLmain $(SHARED_LIB) -lSDL

    install: $(STATIC_LIB) $(SHARED_LIB)
cp $(STATIC_LIB) $(SHARED_LIB) $(IMPORT_LIB) $(lib_dir)
cp SDL_framerate.h SDL_gfxPrimitives.h SDL_imageFilter.h SDL_rotozoom.h $(include_dir)/SDL

    uninstall:
rm -f $(lib_dir)/$(STATIC_LIB)
rm -f $(lib_dir)/$(SHARED_LIB)
rm -f $(lib_dir)/$(IMPORT_LIB)
rm -f $(include_dir)/SDL/SDL_framerate.h
rm -f $(include_dir)/SDL/SDL_gfxPrimitives.h
rm -f $(include_dir)/SDL/SDL_imageFilter.h
rm -f $(include_dir)/SDL/SDL_rotozoom.h

    clean:
rm -f *.o *.a *.dll
rm -f Test/*.o Test/*.exe
```

**Parts from 'SDL_gfxPrimitives.c'; line 435-445 and 773-785**

```
    /*435-445*/
    #ifdef ALPHA_PIXEL_ADDITIVE_BLEND
                    A = (dA | GFX_ALPHA_ADJUST_ARRAY[alpha & 255]) << Ashift; // make destination less transparent...
    #else
                    A = ((dA + ((((color & Amask) >> Ashift) - dA) * alpha >> 8)) << Ashift) & Amask;
    #endif
                    *pixel |= A;
                }
            }
        }
        break;
    #endif

    /*773-785*/
    #ifdef ALPHA_PIXEL_ADDITIVE_BLEND
                        A = (dA | GFX_ALPHA_ADJUST_ARRAY[sA & 255]) << Ashift; // make destination less transparent...
    #else
                        A = ((dA + ((sA - dA) * alpha >> 8)) << Ashift) & Amask;
    #endif
                        *pixel |= A;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    break;
    #endif
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should modify Makefile according to the following steps:

1.
Change:

```
OBJS = SDL_framerate.o SDL_gfxPrimitives.o SDL_imageFilter.o SDL_rotozoom.o

To:

OBJS = SDL_framerate.o SDL_gfxBlitFunc.o SDL_gfxPrimitives.o SDL_imageFilter.o SDL_rotozoom.o
```

2.
Change:

```
cp SDL_framerate.h SDL_gfxPrimitives.h SDL_imageFilter.h SDL_rotozoom.h $(include_dir)/SDL
```

To:

```
cp SDL_framerate.h SDL_gfxBlitFunc.h SDL_gfxPrimitives.h SDL_imageFilter.h SDL_rotozoom.h $(include_dir)/SDL
```

3.
Add: `rm -f $(include_dir)/SDL/SDL_gfxBlitFunc.h`

Between

```
rm -f $(include_dir)/SDL/SDL_framerate.h
```

And

```
rm -f $(include_dir)/SDL/SDL_gfxPrimitives.h
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I finally got the DLL. Would you please explain, what these changes mean and why they have to be made? I see, that you added the 'gfxBlitFunc' to several lines, but why are they needed?